# Como ativar 2 if's ao mesmo tempo em Python

Tags: python-3.x, if, pyautogui

Estou fazendo um bot que joga GuitarFlash (Guitar Hero de browser) sozinho,só que, quando preciso que ele aperte as duas teclas de notas ao mesmo tempo (uso o pyautogui para apertar as teclas e o ImageGrab para detectar a nota) ele aperta um de cada vez ao invés dos 2 juntos

```py
import time

from PIL import ImageGrab
import pyautogui

"""
Resolução:1366 x 768
Guitar Flash 1

"""

def capture_screen():
    screen = ImageGrab.grab()
    return screen

def detect_green(screen): #pegar o pixel das cores
    color = screen.getpixel((493, 652))
    if color == (255, 255, 255):
        return True

def green(): 
    pyautogui.press("1")

def detect_red(screen): 
    color = screen.getpixel((582, 652))
    if color == (255, 255, 255):
        return True

def red(): 
    pyautogui.press("2")

def detect_yellow(screen):
    color = screen.getpixel((672, 652))
    if color == (255, 255, 255):
        return True

def yellow():
    pyautogui.press("3")

def detect_blue(screen):
    color = screen.getpixel((761, 652))
    if color == (255, 255, 255):
        return True

def blue():
    pyautogui.press("9")

def detect_orange(screen):
    color = screen.getpixel((851, 652))
    if color == (255, 255, 255):
        return True

def orange():
    pyautogui.press("0")

def active_special(screen):
    color = screen.getpixel((867, 572))
    if color == (0, 141, 255):
        return True

def special():
    pyautogui.press("space")

print('3')
time.sleep(1)
print('2')
time.sleep(1)
print('1')
time.sleep(1)
print('Start')


while True:
    screen = capture_screen()
    if detect_green(screen):
        green()
    if detect_red(screen):
        red()
    if detect_yellow(screen):
        yellow()
    if detect_blue(screen):
        blue()
    if detect_orange(screen):
        orange()
    if active_special(screen):
        special()
```

Teria alguma forma de fazer ele apertar os 2 botões juntos? Ele está detectando porém quando ele da o comando para apertar vai um de cada vez.

Comment: vc pode usar o `and` para fazer duas comparações iguais

Comment: eu tentei fazer isso, só que ai ele ativa duas vezes, pq ele detecta o do if normal e o do and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para pressionar 2 botões juntos, basta fazer `pyautogui.hotkey('1', '2')`. Isto faz com que ele pressione na ordem e solte na ordem inversa, como descrito [aqui](https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html#the-hotkey-function).

Agora, basta pegar quais cores estão ativas e passar para o `pyautogui.hotkey()`:

```
while True:        
    if detect_green(screen):
        colors_detected.append("1")
    if detect_red(screen):
        colors_detected.append("2")
    if detect_yellow(screen):
        colors_detected.append("3")
    if detect_blue(screen):
        colors_detected.append("9")
    if detect_orange(screen):
        colors_detected.append("0")
    if active_special(screen):
        colors_detected.append("space")

    pyautogui.press(*colors_detected)
```

Repare que fazer `*lista` ([unpacking](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)) me permite passar cada elemento da lista como um argumento.